# Is it preferable to validate user input(using Editing Changed event)as user types text rather than performing all validation once user taps a button?

Tags: ios, regex, validation

Performance wise in swift when using regex to validate user input in a form

- first name
- last name
- email
- password

is it preferable to validate the text field text as the user enters it using an Editing Changed event for the text field action outlet?

**or**

is validating the full string after the user taps a button (or submits the form) the better option?

Comment: Are you implying that there is one text field that the user must enter 4 comma separated values? I hope not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have done something horribly wrong, your regex-based validation should be so fast that the time spent there is unnoticeable to the user. So you should perform validation in whatever way provides the best user experience, which probably means doing it on every change to the input.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to me a non-technical question or at least that's what I think the answer is. I would read 'better' as in terms of user experience. For your app would the user find it a better experience to get all the errors at the end or as he or she is typing and filling out those fields?